# Azure Key vault - How to backup and restore?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

How to backup and restore the Azure Key vault that includes keys, secrets & cert along with RBAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you can use Powershell or CLI to achieve this.  after you have done an az login.

**keys**
Export-AzKeyVaultKey and Import-AzKeyVaultKey commands in Azure PowerShell or the az keyvault key export and az keyvault key import commands in Azure CLI to export and import keys and secrets.

**Certs**
Export-AzKeyVaultCertificate and Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate commands in Azure PowerShell or the az keyvault certificate export and az keyvault certificate import commands in Azure CLI.

**RBAC policies**
Get-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy and Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy commands in Azure PowerShell or the az keyvault show and az keyvault set-policy

CLI example of how to export the keys, certs and RBAC policies to a local file

```
# Authenticate to Azure
az login

# Export keys, secrets, and certificates from the key vault
keyVaultName="<key-vault-name>"
exportFolderPath="<export-folder-path>"

az keyvault key export --name "<key-name>" --vault-name $keyVaultName --file "$exportFolderPath/key.json"
az keyvault secret export --name "<secret-name>" --vault-name $keyVaultName --file "$exportFolderPath/secret.json"
az keyvault certificate export --name "<certificate-name>" --vault-name $keyVaultName --file "$exportFolderPath/certificate.json"

# Export RBAC policies from the key vault
keyVault=$(az keyvault show --name $keyVaultName)
accessPolicies=$keyVault.properties.accessPolicies
echo $accessPolicies > "$exportFolderPath/access-policies.json"
```

If you wanted to restore those from the local file to another key vault this will the CLI way to do it

```
az keyvault key import --name "<key-name>" --vault-name $keyVaultName --file "$exportFolderPath/key.json"
az keyvault secret import --name "<secret-name>" --vault-name $keyVaultName --file "$exportFolderPath/secret.json"
az keyvault certificate import --name "<certificate-name>" --vault-name $keyVaultName --file "$exportFolderPath/certificate.json"

accessPolicies=$(cat "$exportFolderPath/access-policies.json")

az keyvault set-policy --name $keyVaultName --access-policies $accessPolicies
```

**To Back up and restore an entire keyvault**

```
Backup-AzKeyVault -VaultName <vault_name> -FilePath <file_path>
Restore-AzKeyVault -VaultName <vault_name> -FilePath <file_path>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/backup-azkeyvault?view=azps-9.2.0

Comment: Is there a way to back up the key vault all together(like VM backup) instead of taking backups individual keys, secret.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar yes you can use the backup-azkeyvault and restore-azkeyvault, I have updated, if it helps please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to backup and restore the Azure key vault using the portal?

Answer (score 1):

AS **Ricky Gummadi** said One way is you can use PowerShell or CLI to achieve this.

The other method to Backup and Restore keys, secrets, certificates is through Azure portal is as follows

To backup and restore the Azure Key vault follow the Reference [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/backup?tabs=azure-cli).

**Keys Backup in Key Vault:**

In key vault select created keys and click on Download Backup

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Secrets Backup in Key Vault:**

Select created Secret then click on Download Backup

[image]

[image]

**Certificates Backup in Key Vault:**

[image]

[image]

**Restore**:

1. Select your key vault.
2. Go to the type of object (secret, key, or certificate) you want to restore.
3. Select **Restore Backup**.
4. Go to the location where you stored the encrypted blob.
5. Select **OK**.

Reference [link](https://zimmergren.net/backup-azure-key-vault-secrets-keys-certificates/)